# Setting first three recommended videos in youtube

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I would like to know if there is anyway I can set the first three videos to be shown as recommended videos for a particular video feed using youtube api.

Answer (score 0):

That's not something that you can control using the YouTube API. There are no plans that I'm aware of to add in that functionality.